# Git: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2, ssh

I've never cloned a private GitHub repository. So I followed GitHub's guide but it's still rejecting me. I have a Red Hat linux server on AWS. I did the following:

1. Ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "< my github email address >"`.
2. Ran `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`.
3. Ran `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.
4. Ran `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (to get the value of the key).
5. Added output of step 4 into here: https://github.com/settings/keys.
6. Ran `ssh -T git@github.com` and it outputted this:

   > Hi AskYous! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
   >   provide shell access.
7. Ran `sudo git clone git@github.com:AskYous/google-code-challange.git` (a private repository I own). This is when I got the following error:

   > Cloning into 'google-code-challange'... Permission denied (publickey).
   >   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
   >
   > Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
   >   exists.
8. I checked GitHub and it acknowledges that the key has been used: [image]

Comment: Have you tried `ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /somewhere/yourkey; git clone git@github.com:AskYous/google-code-challange.git'`?

Comment: I just ran `sudo ssh-agent bash -c ~/.ssh/id_rsa;` and it says `bash: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied`.

Comment: Run without using `sudo` (sudo does not necessay cause you are in your home directory)

Comment: I got the same thing. Here's a screenshot of running it with sudo and without: https://imgur.com/izUbFYf

Comment: Make you have permission: `$ chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Weird. I logged out of SSH and logged in and it worked. I don't know what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, and I don't know how this happened, is that the private key changed so this new key was not stored on GitHub. It changed somehow. Perhaps I ran the generation process twice.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to help anyone who's experiencing this issue as I spent a while trying to resolve.
Make sure the key pairs ownership owned by buildkite-agent

[-rw-r--r--. 1 buildkite-agent buildkite-agent  749 Jul 27 13:34 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------. 1 buildkite-agent buildkite-agent 3243 Jul 27 13:34 id_rsa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiq8H.png)